# How do I send complex objects back to the controller for the purposes of paging?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I simply couldn't properly describe this in the title.

We have a history of user events for our product that is displayed as paged and lets you set the number of events per page as well as filtering the results on several of the columns if you want to. The filters used to work as just a single selection. For example there would be a drop down list for the type of the event, and you could select just one of them and filter on that. I added support for selecting multiple choices in each of the filter drop down lists and now paging doesn't work.

What it does right now is generate ActionLinks for each of the page numbers, the previous/next page links, and the links that change the number of events per page. Since they were just single selections before it was pretty easy to just put those values in as routevalues and send them off to the controller which would use them to return the properly filtered data for the next page. Now I have a mixture of simple enum values (some drop downs are still just single selection) and lists of enum values.

I'm receiving the filter data on my page as a RouteValueDictionary so I have to check if the value is an object or a list of objects before I can even do anything proper with it, which strikes me as ugly.

So in short, I need to generate links that send filter options back to the controller. Some of the filter options will be an enum keyed by a string, and some will be a list of enums keyed by a string. These filter options are available to me on the view side all together in a `<string, object`> dictionary.

I just can't figure out what the 'nice' way of doing this is.

Let me know if you need to know anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I take it as a given that when your filter is updated you need to refresh the results page. If this is the case, I'd do some jQuery Ajax to handle the whole thing instead of modifying link urls. The reason I'd switch to Ajax is because it is easy to create an object that you'd like to send to the server with it whereas sending a complex object as a query string is not so easy. You'd have something like that:

```js
$(document).on('click','selector of your filter inputs', function(){
    $.Ajax({
        url: '/[Controller]/[Action]',
        type: 'GET',
        data: { filter1: $('input').val()... }, // however complex object you need
        success: function(data){
            $('selector of the result container').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yeah, doing ajax does seem like the way to go. I came to this company less than a month ago and it's a very basic web app. Nothing is ajax, it's all full refreshes to do everything. I'm just not sure if I'm going to be given the 'jurisdiction' to change all the required things over to javascript, as that will take longer than whatever weird thing I'm going to have to do to make it work within the current architecture.